# Is Huion Kamvas Pro 13 supported?

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I'm thinking of gifting a drawing tablet to a person who uses Ubuntu. I had my eyes on the Huion Kamvas Pro 13 and I would like to know if it is supported before making a terrible mistake. However, I couldn't find any clear information online and the related questions here on AskUbuntu are quite outdated.

Answer (score 5):

I plugged my kamvas 13 pro in a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it works :

- full-hd screen recognized
- stylus working well as mouse
- stylus pressure working in blender !!
- multi-monitor setup (except for the stylus, see below)

What **does not work** out-of-the-box :

- tablet buttons and slider
- forcing the stylus area to a single monitor (tablet) ; the stylus moves to the entire desktop

To force the stylus area read
[input coordinates transformation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation)
and
[tranformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).

It works with this xinput fix :

```
xinput set-prop 15 --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.5 0 0.25 0 0.333333 0.666666 0 0 1
```

... here is my monitors setup :

- 4K monitor on top
- full-HD kamvas monitor below centered

I can now work on blender with my kamvas pro 13 in a dual-monitor config !!!!

Comment: On my side, I tried my Huion KAMVAS Pro 12 GT-116 on two PCs (desktop PC and a laptop) with Linux Mint 20.1 (which is based on Ubuntu). Everything works fine on the laptop which has a 1920x1080 resolution that matches that of the tablet. However, On my desktop PC, I found that I had to lower the screen resolution from 2560x1440 to 1920x1080 to get it to work properly.

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04 and the application Krita, then everything works fine with Huion Kamvas Pro 13.

Answer (score 2):

Huion does not offer a Linux driver, but you can go to this website and it offers huion for some linux versions: https://github.com/Huion-Linux.

Comment: Thanks. The model I mentioned is not in the list of officially supported devices, unfortunately (https://digimend.github.io/drivers/digimend/tablets/). Does this mean it will not work or only that the list is not updated?

Comment: The list is probably not updated, but you can still try it though. If it doesn't work you can try this: http://www.magicbluesmoke.org/getting-a-huion-hs610-working-in-linux/ it seems to works for most people.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Huion pro 13 setup and working without using any dkms kernel drivers. I recomend the kamvas-driver python driver from here: https://pypi.org/project/kamvas-driver/.

Settting up the driver was not very difficult,  sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip && sudo pip3 install kamvas-driver && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev

Once those commands are finished run kamvas -c in your home directory to generate a configuration file. then run kamvas start or kamvas stop to respectively start or stop the driver. You can set what your buttons do in the ~/.kamvas_config.yaml file. In your control panel settings set your monitors to mirror, enjoy your new working Huion tablet!

Comment: I forgot the most critical part of the install, install the xserver-xorg-input-evdev driver with sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev before running kamvas -c or kamvas start. My bad :)

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer and include that valuable information!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my Huion Pro 13 working (including buttons) on ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10 with kamvas-driver python as suggested by Michael (thanks a lot!) . But I had some issue, here is how I solved it if someone is interested:

- I had to change product_id in ~/.kamvas_config.yaml (i used lsusb to get the proper value)
- I had to change default_display in ~/.kamvas_config.yaml (i used xrandr to get the proper value)
- I had to set /usr/bin/python to refer to python3. I used :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

- I added a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf containing:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev tablet catchall"
    MatchIsTablet "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```